# How to delete images without annotations?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

I have a folder containing thousands of images. Some images have a txt file with the same name. For example abc.jpg and abc.txt. I want to keep these images and remove all images which do not have a txt file with them. Is there a method to do this?

Comment: what environment and tool do you want to use, windows command line? in python program? something else?

Comment: Either one. windows cmd or python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will move all `.jpg`, `.png`, `.jpeg` and their respective `.txt` files to a new folder.

```
import os
import shutil
folderdir = "folder_path"
dirs = os.listdir(folderdir)
for i in dirs:
    if i.endswith(".txt"):
        txt = i
        jpg = str(i.split(".txt")[0]) + ".jpg"
        png = str(i.split(".txt")[0]) + ".png"
        jpeg = str(i.split(".txt")[0]) + ".jpeg"
        try:
            shutil.move(folderdir + "/" + jpg, 'dataset')
            shutil.move(folderdir + "/" + txt, 'dataset')
        
        except:
            try:
                shutil.move(folderdir + "/" + png, 'dataset')
                shutil.move(folderdir + "/" + txt, 'dataset')
            except:
                shutil.move(folderdir + "/" + jpeg, 'dataset')
                shutil.move(folderdir + "/" + txt, 'dataset')

print("DONE")
```